# Pandas: How to add the sum of a group to the max value of the group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, max

I have three columns on a pandas `df`: `id, hazard, probability`

I want to make sure the sum of probabilities for each id, hazard combo is 1.

So I wanted to find the sum of probabilities for each id, hazard.

And also find the index of the max probability for each id, hazard, and add to that value the 1-sum.

I found in stack overflow how to do these two separately, but can't find a way to combine them.

Find index of max value per group:

```
i = df.groupby(['id','haz'])['prob'].transform('idxmax').values
```

Find sum of probabilities per group:

```
sums= df.groupby(['id','haz'])['prob'].sum()
```

How can I combine these two to make sure that the sum of probabilities for each group is exactly 1?

My code so far and example df below

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

File = 'testprob1.csv'

VF = pd.read_csv(f'{File}', sep=',', header=0, index_col=False, dtype='str')
VF = VF.astype({'id': 'str', 'haz': 'int16', 'prob': 'float64'})

i = VF.groupby(['id','haz'])['prob'].transform('idxmax').values

sums= VF.groupby(['id','haz'])['prob'].sum()
```

Edit:
Example df

[image]

Comment: Please reformat your answer following the guide. Enclose code snippets in ` and provide examples (they don't need to be your data but similar)

Comment: can you share a dummy `df` that you mention with the 3 columns?

Comment: added a sample df

Comment: @AkshaySehgal added also the code I have so far with a sample df

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

1. `new_proba` calculates the new values of probability for each group that they need to replace their max values.
2. Then, you can use `idxmax` to find the row indexes and `df.loc` to find those rows and update them with the `new_proba`

```
new_proba = df.groupby(['id','haz'])['prob'].apply(lambda x: max(x)+1-(sum(x))).values
df.loc[df.groupby(['id','haz'])['prob'].agg('idxmax').values, 'prob'] = new_proba

print(df)
```

```
   id  haz  prob
0   1   20  0.05
1   1   20  0.05
2   1   20  0.90
3   1   30  0.98
4   1   30  0.02
5   2   30  1.00
6   2   40  0.12
7   2   40  0.78
8   2   40  0.05
9   2   40  0.05
```

---

#### Alternate method

For your custom rescaling function, you can write your own function and apply it to each group. Then return the new probability as a list, which once you pass into a `pd.Series` gets distributed as it would when you use `.transform`.

```
idd = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]
haz = [20,20,20,30,30,30,40,40,40,40]
prob = [0.05,0.05,0.42,0.3,0.02,0.05,0.12,0.44,0.05,0.05]
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':idd, 'haz':haz, 'prob':prob})

def f(l):
    return [i+(1-sum(l)) if i==max(l) else i for i in l]

df['new_proba'] = df.groupby(['id','haz'])['prob'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(f(x))).values
print(df)
```

```
   id  haz  prob  new_proba
0   1   20  0.05       0.05
1   1   20  0.05       0.05
2   1   20  0.42       0.90
3   1   30  0.30       0.98
4   1   30  0.02       0.02
5   2   30  0.05       1.00
6   2   40  0.12       0.12
7   2   40  0.44       0.78
8   2   40  0.05       0.05
9   2   40  0.05       0.05
```

Just to confirm that sum for each group is 1 -

```
df.groupby(['id','haz'])['new_proba'].sum()
```

```
id  haz
1   20     1.0
    30     1.0
2   30     1.0
    40     1.0
Name: new_proba, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. However, I want only the max value to change not all of them.
So the max value will be prob+ (1-sum(prob)) for each group

Comment: I dont quite understand. Do you want to change the probability by `prob+(1-sum(prob))`? where the sum is the sum of probs for that group? I dont understand where max is being used

Comment: in the first group for id=1 and haz=20, the max probability which is 0.42 will become 0.9 by adding to it 1-(0.42+0.05+0.05)

Comment: All the other probabilities will remain the same, only the max value will change by adding 1 minus the sum of all probabilities in the group.
I basically want the difference to go to the max value of each group not be equally distributed to all of them

Comment: ah ok, so only one value changes. ok

Comment: Updated my answer do check.

Comment: Added another method, which is cleaner.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much.